# What Christian companies, today, have no name by which they are known?

Tags: global-christianity

In Revelation chapters one to three, there is a woman named Jezebel, whom Christ marks out as impenitent, Revelation 2:21; there is a sect, the Nicolaitans, whose deeds, Revelation 2:6, and doctrine, Revelation 2:15, Christ says he hates and he identifies them as being in both Ephesus and Pergamos; and there is a synagogue where falsely named 'Jews' meet whom Christ identifies in Philadelphia, Revelation 3:9, and he calls them liars.

But of the faithful, Christ mentions only one, in Pergamos - Antipas, who is deceased, a martyr, Revelation 2:13.

In these three chapters, He names no other individual and he names no other company by any communal name. He just states what town they are in.

If one wanted to go and meet them, one has no address (other than the town) and no description other than their characteristics - which he describes.

My question is - are there any towns in the world, today, where a company of Christians meet together, yet have no identifying 'label' (other than the name of Christ, of course) ?

Comment: What do you mean by the word "company" in this question?

Comment: In the context of the seven messages to the seven churches, I think a 'company' would be a true _ekklesia_, that is to say persons called by the gospel who gather together in assembly and also break bread from house to house - an hospitable company which also congregates.

Comment: That certainly makes sense now that I understand the usage. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The only ‘label’ that matters is the ‘label’ of Christian.  A Christian is a person who belongs to Christ Jesus and who obeys Him.  Denominational labels are man-made and of no importance.  Jesus knows who belong to Him and His Church is not a denomination or a building but is a world-wide living entity made up of believers.  The short answer to your question is yes, there are lots of Christians around the world who meet regularly to worship God and study the Bible but who do not belong to any particular denomination.

A denomination is a church organization that exercises some sort of authority over the local churches that comprise it.  There are many Christians who meet together, in private homes or in rented halls, who do not have any identifying ‘label.’  Often, they are categorised as being non-denominational, which simply means they do not come under the authority of a specific denomination.   Non-denominational should never be confused with inter-denominational which is a church or an organization that incorporate different practices from various denominations.  The measure of any church, whether inside or out of a denomination, is not how it is organized nor what name it is called, but rather how faithfully it adheres to the teachings of the Word of God.

It is important to remember that the Body of Christ is interdenominational. We may choose labels for ourselves and others—and such labels have their place—but Jesus never assigned denominational tags. He said, “All those the Father gives me will come to me, and whoever comes to me I will never drive away” (John 6:37). The Body of Christ is made up of “everyone who calls upon the name of the Lord” (Acts 2:21), and the gospel of salvation by grace through faith unites all born-again believers who belong to Christ Jesus.

As for the events, persons and churches recorded in the first three chapters of Revelation, I found a useful article, part of which says this:

> "A normal hermeneutic or normal interpretation of Scripture means that unless the verse or passage clearly indicates the author was using figurative language, it should be understood in its normal sense. We are not to look for other meanings if the natural meaning of the sentence makes sense. Also, we are not to spiritualize Scripture by assigning meanings to words or phrases when it is clear the author, under the guidance of the Holy Spirit, meant it to be understood as it is written.
>
> A simple outline for the book of Revelation is found in Revelation 1:19. In chapter one, the risen and exalted Christ is speaking to John. Christ tells John to “write, therefore, what you have seen, what is now and what will take place later.” The things John had already seen are recorded in chapter 1. The “things which are” (that were present in John's day) are recorded in chapters 2–3 (the letters to the churches). The “things that will take place” (future things) are recorded in chapters 4–22."  Source: https://www.gotquestions.org/Book-Revelation.html

Clearly, there is a warning to all Christians today against falling into sin and/or following false teachers.  Christians are identified by their words and deeds, by holding fast to the truth of God's Word and by showing Christ-like love to all persons.  By their fruits (the fruit of the Spirit) they will be known.

Comment: A good point that you distinguish non-denominational from inter-denominational. (+1).

Comment: Jesus in the Bible (Ephesians2:20) clearly describes and founded a Church, citing Revelation and interpreting a dificult book not in line with the Authors intention will be subject to error. As Apostles clearly states in 2Peter1:20..No prophecy are subject to private interpretation. Just clarifying biblical basis of interpretating the prophecy in Book of Revelation. Thanks. Godblesss

Comment: @jong ricafort  Thanks for your comment and I agree with you that no prophecy can be subject to private interpretation.  As to the church Jesus established “The disciples were called Christians first at Antioch” around 47 C.E. (Hebrews 11:26). That is how Jesus’ followers are known.  It is a body of believers made up of people who belong to Christ. The church is not a denomination.  Christians are identified by the indwelling of the Holy Spirt and transformed lives, lives that produce the fruit of the Spirit.

Comment: @Lesley I'm a bit confused on your answer relating to body of believers in Antioch identifying it as bible believers due to in 47C.E the gospel is not yet written.And the body of believers in Book of Revelation you answered is the same body of bible believers. It seems to me a bit confusing. Thanks.

Comment: @ jong ricafort  My apologies - the scripture was Acts, not Hebrews, and Acts was written circa 63 A.D. The Bible doesn’t give a date when the disciples were first called Christians, but that date is arrived at by tracing the events that led up to the time when the church in Antioch was established. “Christian” means “belonging to Christ.”  And yes, the body of believers in Revelation are also identified as “Christians.” The point is that wherever the church was established those who belonged to Christ were known as Christians. Initially, Christians were seen as a sect of Judaism.

Comment: @Lesley Sorry as a Catholic, there is St. Ignatius of Antioch.. In the First Century Christian belong to a Church Jesus founded..Jesus did not founded a sect of Judaism.im just trying to express and say simply  I dont agree with your view.Godbless

Comment: @jong ricafort - I know Jesus did not found a sect of Judaism. Jesus's disciples were identified as being followers of "the Way".  It was the Romans who viewed the followers of Jesus as a sect of Judaism (initially).  That view quickly ended when the first century Christians refused to worship the Emperor and they were no longer protected as the Jews were.

Comment: @jong ricafort - ‘The History of Christianity’, Lion, 1977 pages 70 to 72:
"As long as the church was regarded simply as a Jewish sect, it was tolerated by the Roman authorities. For its first thirty years Christianity, like Judaism, enjoyed protection by Roman law... Jews were specially exempted from taking part in the cult of emperor-worship. Christians also sought this exemption, since they recognized only one God and served one Lord, Jesus Christ. But when the church became largely composed of Gentiles, it was no longer possible to shelter under the wing of Judaism."

Comment: @Lesley your rreference is year 1977.I would like to introduce you to St. Ignatius of Antioch year 100AD "where ever there appears a bishop, there is the Catholic Church".Godbless

Comment: @jong ricafort - I thought "Catholic" originally meant Universal. All I know (from the Bible) is that the church Jesus is head of was not called Catholic, or Protestant, but was simply known as "the way" until the disciples of Jesus in Antioch were called Christians (before 100 A.D.). If we belong to Christ Jesus and have been born-again, then we are Christians and are part of the body of His Church.  He knows who we are. However, I fear we may now be going off-topic, and since this question is now on hold, it may soon be closed down.  Which would be a great pity.

Comment: @Lesley it wil be closed because you do not follow scriptures 2Peter1:20, you made a personal interpretation of a prophecy which the Apostles prohibited. Godbless

Comment: @jong ricafort – Thanks for the “heads-up” but I am at a loss to understand where, exactly, I am supposed to have “made a personal interpretation of a prophecy.”  I can’t see it myself, but if you point out the offending section I could then at least edit it.  Either that or the person who asked this question can correct me.

Comment: @jong ricafort - Could you kindly stop going on in an oblique manner about your predilection for all things Catholic? Your comments are going to get this perfectly good question, and this perfectly reasonable answer closed down. Comments are not for airing personal hobby-horses. Thank you.

Comment: @Anne Being a Bible Christian I thought you follow biblical teaching, Book of Revelation are prophecy and apostles reminded us of no  private interpretation.Just want say for us not to be lead into error. I dont mean to offend anyone. But the Word hurts because of Heb4:12.The question is in Revelation. Godbless

Comment: @jong ricafort - I made one comment (above) but I did not offer an answer to this Q, let alone an interpretation.  You seem to be labouring under the misapprehension that I am Lesley, who DID answer the Q which you took her to task for. I am not Lesley.